# Why do CD's shatter in a microwave?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, home-experiment

Why have I heard that eggs and CD's and DVD's explode when microwaved?

Comment: Is your oven safe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eggs could explode. They are pretty much sealed so if you heat them fast enough the fluid inside may boil and the pressure builds up. If the shell doesn't crack and relieve the pressure it may explode

CDs have a coating of conductive aluminium (at least pressed CDs rather than home written). The microwave induces a current in the metal layer which heats up because the thin layer has a relatively high resistance. This heat is then transferred to one side of the plastic base which expands and could shatter